# remove html tags from a html content in c# using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a big html content. And from that I have to remove the following text from that HTML content.

```
<span id="sso-container"><span class="username">{Inner text could be anything}</span></span>
```

In the above mentioned snippet  "{Inner text could be anything}" means that could be any text.

In the whole HTML wherever

```
<span id="sso-container"><span class="username">{Inner text could be anything}</span></span>
```

is present, it will be replaced by some fixed text.

can anyone suggest what will be the regex expression for this requirement.

Comment: Please post the HTML content as well, it would make it easier to help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get text between 2 html tags c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193105/get-text-between-2-html-tags-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

I would really suggest you to use [HTMLAgility](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) pack over RegEx.

please read this **[Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1155650)** before you decide to go for RegEx based solution. you can find the regex based answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11193214/1155650) SO Question.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument;
doc.Load(htmlstring);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span"); 
//Here, you can also do something like (".//span[@id='sso-container' class='username')    
string value = node.InnerText; 
//this string will contain the value of span, i.e. <span>***value***</span>
```

Comment: He wanted to remove the text. This will only locate the text. Also this would find all <span>'s

Comment: You can always do string replace with the orginal html string. also i believe getting the **username** was more important for the OP than removing unwanted stuffs from the input html string.

Comment: Well, i read the question as, "I have to remove the following text from a HTML content"

Comment: @OddmarDam - Go ahead and check OP's answer to the question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30457433/1155650

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = @"<span id=""sso-container""><span class=""username"">.*?</span></span>";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern);
        bool test = regex.IsMatch(@"<span id=""sso-container""><span class=""username"">dynamic</span></span>");
```

Its working...

Comment: and how does the bool values remove any html content?